# Checking if a div is visible or hidden and toggleing a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple check box's in a row. When a button is clicked it shows a div (#locale_container), and a small arrow is flipped (through adding a rotated class).

However I don't want the arrow to flip every time the checkbox is checked, only when the div is visible or hidden.

i.e 
if checkbox 1 is checked then rotate (div is hidden then visible), then if it is unchecked rotate again (div is visible then hidden).

if checkbox 2 and checkbox 3 are checked rotate, but if checkbox 3 is unchecked and checkbox 2 still checked don't rotate.

This is what i've managed to build so far but can't seem to get it to work!

How do I get it to stop rotating every time the box is checked - checking when the div is visible or hidden!

```
$(document).on('change', '#est', function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#locale_container" ).slideDown( "Medium");

    if (!$('#locale_container').is(':visible'))
    {
        console.log("hidden");
        $("#locale_arrow").toggleClass('flip');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("visible"); 
    }

    console.log("Check")
});
```

EDIT: JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/10yf47an/2/

My HTML

```
  <div class="inner" id="est">
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox"><span>Club</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" id="est">
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox"><span>Pub</span></label>
  </div>



<img id="locale_arrow" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/7/7645.svg" >
      <div id="locale_container">
   DEMO</div>
```

My CSS

```
#locale_container {display:none}

.flip {transform: rotate(-180deg);}

#locale_arrow {height: 40px}
```

Comment: How do you hide/show divs? If you use opacity, you can check if it's value is 0 or 1, if you set "display: none" you can check if it's set, etc..

Comment: i'm using display:none

Comment: At first sight your code should work, can you provide a working codepen/fiddle?

Comment: Ill make a fiddle! Give me a couple of mins - Thanks!

Comment: @ThoughtsRiff Just added a fiddle! Basically when "DEMO" is visible and another checkbox has been checked then the arrow shouldn't flip! - thanks for your help!

Comment: You seem to have some syntax errors, **1:** an `id` **must** be unique for the page to be valid (X)HTML, **2:** you have a closing `</div>` without an opening `<div>` tag, **3:** you have an unnecessary semi-colon following the closing `}` of your `else`. Also: please post your "*[mcve]*" code in your question, the JS Fiddle demo is a bonus but it's not a replacement for your code being present in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i provide a snippet example with what i have undestood you want, just tellme if it works as expected.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.inner', function (e)
{
    // Get number of checkboxes checked.

    var counter = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    console.log("Checkboxs checked number: " + counter);
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (counter > 0 && !$('#locale_container').is(':visible'))
    {
        $("#locale_container").slideDown("Medium");
        $("#locale_arrow").addClass("flip");
    }
    else if (counter <= 0)
    {
        $("#locale_container").slideUp("Medium");
        $("#locale_arrow").removeClass("flip");
    }
});
```

```css
#locale_container {display:none}

.flip {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

#locale_arrow {height: 40px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inner">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"><span>Club</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="inner">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"><span>Pub</span>
    </label>
</div>
  
<img id="locale_arrow" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/7/7645.svg" >

<div id="locale_container">DEMO</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works exactly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version which works:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exdfaLjc/)

HTML:

```
 <div class="inner" id="est">
 <label>
   <input class="est" type="checkbox"><span>Club</span></label>
   </div>
   <div class="inner">
   <label>
   <input  class="est" type="checkbox"><span>Pub</span></label>
   </div>

 <img id="locale_arrow" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/7/7645.svg" ></div>
       <div id="locale_container">DEMO</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.est').on('click', function (e) {

        if (!$('#locale_container').is(':visible')) {
        $("#locale_arrow").toggleClass('flip');
      $( "#locale_container" ).slideDown( "Medium");
        console.log("hidden");
        } else {
        console.log("visible"); 
    }
     console.log("Check")
    });
});
```

The problem was that the "slidedown" method toggle the visibility of the element, so you couldn't check properly.

Comment: Ok - Understood! Thanks

Comment: I have a demo (https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g13xod4u/) that disagrees with your claim that the "*[change] event doesn't work on [checkboxes]*."

Comment: You're right! I just misread on jquery api reference! It works on it, just fired immediately.